# Symlinked folder on subdomain gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: permissions, symlink, apache

I am trying to transfer a website that is on a local dev server to a live server.
The top domain works fine, but when I try to access the subdomain  I get a 403 forbidden error.

Here is the message in the error log:

```
[Sun Sep 16 13:54:38 2012] [error] [client 108.176.142.194] 
(13)Permission denied: Can't open directory for index: 
/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/models/html/neytiri/, 
referer: http://models.weather-bell.com/html/
```

The directory `neytiri` in `/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/models/html/` is a symlink to `/neytiri` (on the drive's root).

I have set the permissions to 755 for everything I could find, and set the owner and group to root, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd/"
Listen 80
ServerName weatherbell.com
ServerAdmin root@weatherbell.com
DocumentRoot "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com"
NameVirtualHost *:80

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
  StartServers 4
  MinSpareServers 5
  MaxSpareServers 10
  ServerLimit 69
  MaxClients 69
  MaxRequestsPerChild 1000 
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  StartServers 4
  MaxClients 1024
  MinSpareThreads 64
  MaxSpareThreads 192
  ThreadsPerChild 64
  MaxRequestsPerChild 0
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_status.c>
  ExtendedStatus On
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</IfModule>
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
UseCanonicalName Off
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
  <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
    User daemon
    Group daemon
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
  UserDir "disable"
</IfModule>
AccessFileName ".htaccess"
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
  MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>
Alias /icons/ "/home/www/icons/"
Alias /dompdf "/home/www/dompdf/"
Alias /mpdf "/home/www/mpdf/"
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
  DAVLockDB "/var/lib/dav/lockdb"
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>
<Directory "/home/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
  AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
  AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
  AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
  AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
  AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
  AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
  AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
  AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
  AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
  AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
  AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
  AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
  AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
  AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
  AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
  AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
  AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
  AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
  AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
  AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
  AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
  AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
  AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
  AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
DefaultIcon "/icons/unknown.gif"
ReadmeName "README.html"
HeaderName "HEADER.html"
  AddLanguage ca .ca
  AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
  AddLanguage da .dk
  AddLanguage de .de
  AddLanguage el .el
  AddLanguage en .en
  AddLanguage eo .eo
  AddLanguage es .es
  AddLanguage et .et
  AddLanguage fr .fr
  AddLanguage he .he
  AddLanguage hr .hr
  AddLanguage it .it
  AddLanguage ja .ja
  AddLanguage ko .ko
  AddLanguage ltz .ltz
  AddLanguage nl .nl
  AddLanguage nn .nn
  AddLanguage no .no
  AddLanguage pl .po
  AddLanguage pt .pt
  AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
  AddLanguage ru .ru
  AddLanguage sv .sv
  AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
  AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddHandler type-map var
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  <IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/error">
      AllowOverride None
      Options IncludesNOEXEC
      AddOutputFilter Includes html
      AddHandler type-map var
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      LanguagePriority en es de fr
      ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
  BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
  BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
  BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
  BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
  BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
  BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
  BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
  BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
  Alias /tropical "/weatherbell.com/models/neytiri/maue/tropical"
Alias /weather "/weatherbell.com/models/neytiri/maue/weather"
Alias /~maue "/weatherbell.com/models/neytiri/maue/public_html"
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs">
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com">
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
  Allow from All
  Order Allow,Deny
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/models">
  #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/icons">
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/dompdf">
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/mpdf">
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/cgi-bin">
  Options None
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/neytiri/">
   #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/neytiri/maue/weather/">
   #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/models">
   #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/models/neytiri">
   #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName weather-bell.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/public"
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  ErrorLog "logs/weatherbell.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/weatherbell.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName models.weather-bell.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/www/htdocs/weatherbell.com/models"
  Alias /weather "/neytiri/maue/weather"
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  ErrorLog "logs/models.weatherbell.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/models.weatherbell.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory "/home/www/htdocs">
    Options +Indexes
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/home/www/htdocs"
  <Directory "/home/www/htdocs">
    Options +Indexes
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```